# Changing the Uppsala theme in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Theme
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Uppsala}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Graphics
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Math
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\newcommand{\bmf}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath$#1$}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

% Tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2.5}}

% Textboxes
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\textblockcolour{white}

% Other
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{comment}

% Information for title page
\title{My Presentation}
\author{My name}
\date[]{My University}

% Titlepage
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Aim}


\begin{frame}{Aim}
\textbf{My Aim}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is what I want to do
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to change the logo, as I want to adapt this format to my needs. I found that the line of code to include the large logo in the title page is located in the file "uu-all.tex". So i can change it. However, I cannot understand where is the command that produces the logo in the sidebar. I checked all the auxiliary files located in the same folder of my "main.tex". In fact, I do have a file with that logo in the sidebar, but I excluded it from the folder I am working on. Nonetheless, the logo still appears. My questions:

1. Where is located the command that include the logo in the sidebar?
2. Eventually, how can I change the logo in the sidebar?

Below a link to all the aforementioned files.

[Link](https://unimeit-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/dmaimone_unime_it/EcRo4v1J7SxDtJS4yHblKIUBO2-ngEQH1kqKeaVfkOtxqA?e=IjTiOj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name of the logo is hard coded in the headline definition in `uu-main.tex`. You can change it by redefining the headline (search the following code for the comment `<- change image here`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Theme
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Uppsala}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Graphics
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Math
%\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\newcommand{\bmf}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath$#1$}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

% Tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2.5}}

% Textboxes
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\textblockcolour{white}

% Other
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{comment}

% Information for title page
\title{My Presentation}
\author{My name}
\date[]{My University}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth]{logo}
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
    \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
    \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to%
      \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}%
          \ifbeamer@mylogo%
          %% Should be the image file, not the include command
          \pgfimage[width=\beamer@sidebarwidth,height=\beamer@headheight]{\insertlogo}%
          \else%
          \pgfimage[width=\beamer@sidebarwidth,height=\beamer@headheight]{example-image-duck}%uulogo_red160}% <- change image here
          \fi%
        }\vss}\hss}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vskip-\beamer@headheight%
  \hskip\beamer@sidebarwidth%
  %% If we want the subsections at the top
  \ifbeamer@subsectionsattop
  \insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\beamer@mydim}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
  \vskip2ex%
  \else
  %% If we want the shorttitle>section>subsection at the top; 2ex high
  \ifbeamer@sectionpathattop
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@mydim,ht=2ex,dp=1ex,leftskip=1ex]{section in head/foot}%
    {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\usebeamercolor{title in head/foot}%
      \insertshorttitle\strut}%
    {\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}%
      \hspace*{1ex}\insertgotosymbol%~
      \insertsectionhead}%
    \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty%
    \else%
    {\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\usebeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}
      \insertgotosymbol%\hspace*{1ex}
      \insertsubsectionhead}
    \fi%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \else%
  \vskip2ex%
  \fi%
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

% Titlepage
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Aim}


\begin{frame}{Aim}
\textbf{My Aim}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is what I want to do
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly!

Comment: @Dario You're welcome!